# Eloquent - Add extra attributes by default after instantiation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I would like to add a new attribute to an Eloquent model by default. For instance, a `queryTime` attribute.

Because the value of the attributed must be evaluated right after the instantiation, so `getExtraAttribute()` method does not work in my case.

I tried adding:

```
protected $appends = ['time'];
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $attributes['time'] = time();
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

...to the model but it didn't work. `$instance->time` simply returned `null`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the assessor wouldn't work in your use case?

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy Since e.g. `queryTime` would be supposed to return the time when the model was instantiated, however using the assessor would dynamically generate a time stamp when you need the attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple class property, set its default value, then create an accessor for it, like so:

```
protected $time;

protected $appends = ['time']; // only needed if you need `time` in the json/array representation of the model.

public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    $this->time = time();

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}

public function getTimeAttribute()
{ 
    return $this->time;
}
```

Comment: Any difference between the one in my question description? You meant I shouldn't use `$appends`? Or the `$this->`?

Comment: You passed a new array to the parent constructor. That won't work because the parent Model can only define attributes that either come from the database or assessors. My suggestion is to add a new key to your model's `attributes` array instead.

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you keep the `$appends` if you are using this as json.

Comment: 1. Why was it a new array? It was the one from the parameter I think? 2. Mine still returns `null`. May I know the version of Laravel that you're using?

Comment: 1- Take a look at the original `Model.php` constructor - when `fill`is called, Eloquent maps the array you passed to the related table columns. If your table doesn't have a corresponding column, the array key is ignored. 2- I tested it on a 5.1 environment. I'll check 5.4 soon.

Comment: But in Laravel 5.4, it uses `HasAttributes::mutateAttribute()` to evaluate the `$appends`, which simply checks whether `getExtraAttributes()` methods exist otherwise returns `null`

Comment: FYI https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.4.28/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L430

Comment: Confirmed the original suggestion doesn't work on 5.4; I've updated the answer with a new suggestion. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Cool, it worked. So the trick was to use both `$time` and `$appends`! Many thanks!